# Who is Palpatine's Wife?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker, rey

In *[The Rise of Skywalker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker)*, it is revealed

> Rey is Palpatine's granddaughter.

Then who would be Palpatine's wife? I have watched all of the movies and have never heard anything about this.

Comment: You know that people can reproduce without marrying, yeah? (Cloning aside)

Comment: Down-voting for a clear lack of effort. A quick google search or even the wikipedia article for the movie offers the answer...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rey's father [Dathan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dathan) is a clone of Palpatine. He was made in a cloning chamber. There is, by definition, no mother. There are, however, indications that Palpatine may have included foreign DNA in order to try to make his clone a more compatible recipient for his Force essence.

> Anaximander studied the three-dimensional image of Dathan’s face. “He’s a clone?”
>
> “Subject three lacks genetic signatures of accelerated growth. He is thirty-three standard years of age, but analysis shows he is a hybrid strandcast.”
>
> Anaximander shook his head. “Explain.”
>
> “**The strandcast is not a direct cloned replicate of the donor, but is nonetheless created from an engineered template.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Shadows of the Sith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shadow_of_the_Sith)</sup></sub>

Comment: Who's Anaximander?

Comment: @EthanChan - Friend of Lando's. Adminstrator of a mining colony named Nightside.

Comment: as the daughter of his clone, would that really make her his granddaughter, but rather somehow his daughter (or niece, as a clone could be considered somewhat of a twin)?

Comment: @Sursula-they- We don't really have any words in the English language to describe their relationship, hence father, son, granddaughter being used in place of clone, clone's daughter.

Comment: @Valorum alll things considered, I don't think any language has words to describe those kinds of interrelations... . This reminds me of Douglas Adams description of the problem one encounters when trying to use the proper tense while describing time travel in "The restaurant at the end of the universe".